# Class not found error on custom TYPO3 extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have a custom frontend extension that I have installed on TYPO3 10.

I took a snippet of code from another friend extension and I have some problem to declare the hook class:

under hooks I have a file PageLayoutView.php.

```
class PageLayoutView implements \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface {...
```

Then in the ext_localconf.php I have added this line:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['tt_content_drawItem'][$_EXTKEY] = \MyVendor\myTheme\Hooks\PageLayoutView::class;
```

in ext_tables.php file i have the following namespace:

```
call_user_func(
function()
{

    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
        'Myvendor.myExtname',
        'Templates',
        'Ext name'
    );
```

In the backend I get this error:

```
(1/1) Error
Class 'MyVendor\myTheme\Hooks\PageLayoutView' not found
```

what i'm missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to dump the autoload information in the TYPO3 Install Tool?

If it's a composer based installation, try to remove the extension completely and require it again afterwards.

And you should check the namespace in PageLayoutView.php.